# ORA-27101 shared memory real does not exist (Oracle 11g)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have installed oracle 11g, but got this error: "ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified" while I was trying to connect to it from eclipse. I googled alot and finally changed my nls language and territory settings + my windows language and territory settings (from Russian to English(American)). But that didnt solve the problem, so I decided to reinstall the oracle 11g. And got myself a step back in solving the problem by generating another error even before the first error. I tried to manualy set the environmental variable ORACLE_HOME, didnt help. Also I tried to login to the sqlplus as "sysdba" and then to launch the "startup" command. This brought me an error that my "spfilexe.ora" is missing, so maybe that could be the problem. And I have started the oracle database before. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm afraid this sort of problem is not on-topic for this site. What you've described is slightly confusing, and among other things it isn't clear if you completely removed the Oracle installation before trying to install again from scratch. The original Eclipse error just sounds like environment setup though, so reinstalling was probably not necessary - at this point it sounds like it might be as it doesn't sound like it's in a happy state.

Comment: Are you running on Windows?

Comment: Yes, Im running on Windows